# Modifying code to process a long list of strings

Tags: python, arrays, regex, pandas, list

I want to prepare a long list of data for a task.
I have been able to put the code together that gets the task done on a single instance, but now i want to get it to run through a list. Below is what i tried.

single instance for testing.....

```
sentences = ['if the stimulus bill had become hamstrung by a filibuster threat or recalcitrant conservadems']
antecedents = ['bill had become hamstrung by']
```

Actual Use case are two columns in a pandas dataframe, which i have converted to lists

```
f = tra_df['sentence'].tolist()
b = tra_df['antecedent'].tolist()
```

code for single use case....

```
results =[]

ous = 1
ayx = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in antecedents])
ayxx = ayx.split(" ")
antlabels = []    
for i in range(len(ayxx)):

    antlabels.append(ous)
    lab = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in antlabels])



     # Build the regex string required
rx = '({})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(el) for el in antecedents))
     # Generator to yield replaced sentences
it = (re.sub(rx, lab, sentence) for sentence in sentences)
     # Build list of paired new sentences and old to filter out where not the same
results = ([new_sentence for old_sentence, new_sentence in zip(sentences, it) if old_sentence != new_sentence])

# replace other non 1 values with 0
nw_results = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in results])
ew_results= nw_results.split(" ")
new_results = ['0' if i is not '1' else i for i in ew_results]
labels =([int(e) for e in new_results]) 

labels
```

And this is the result i get

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

slightly modified code for the large list

```
for sentences, antecedents in zip(f, b):
    gobels = []
    #def format_labels(antecedents,sentences):
    results =[]
    #lab =[]
    ous = 1
    ayx = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in antecedents])
    ayxx = ayx.split(" ")
    antlabels = []    
    for i in range(len(ayxx)):
        antlabels.append(ous)
        lab = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in antlabels])



     # Build the regex string required
    rx = '({})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(el)for el in antecedents))
     # Generator to yield replaced sentences
    it = (re.sub(rx, lab, sentence)for sentence in sentences)
     # Build list of paired new sentences and old to filter out where not the same
    results = ([new_sentence for old_sentence, new_sentence in zip(sentences, it) if old_sentence != new_sentence])

    nw_results = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in results])
    ew_results= nw_results.split(" ")
    new_results = ['0' if i is not '1' else i for i in ew_results]
    labels =([int(e) for e in new_results]) 

    t2 = time.time()
    gobels.append(labels)
```

Now, instead of a list of list of strings containing 0's and 1's, I get a long list of just 1's.....

What could be wrong?

```
[[1,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  1,
 ........]
```

Comment: what's `ous` from `antlabels.append(ous)`?

Comment: The ous is a placeholder variable, i want to have as many ous (1) as the words i will be replacing.

Comment: thats true, it should have been antlabels.append(bag) but it didnt throw up errors becuase i had declared ia value for it on a previous line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may scale better. There is probably a more pythonic way of doing this still.

```
a = '1 2 3 4 5'
b = '3 4 6'

a = a.split()
b = b.split()

for idx, val in enumerate(b):
    try:
        a[a.index(val)] = True
    except ValueError:
        pass

for idx, val in enumerate(a):
    if val is not True:
        a[idx] = False

print([1.0 if i else 0.0 for i in a])
# [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: This works excellently, but what i want is to to pass two list of lists of strings through it.   a=[' 1 2  3  4 5 ' , '6 7 8 9 10', ' 11 12 13 14 15']  , b=['.....', '......', '...'],

Comment: This method, though seemingly simpler, fails when there are other occurences of parts of string b in string a.